# Can't use Scanner class, constructor is undefined, method is undefined

Tags: java, eclipse

When i want import scanner class in my project eclipse show me some errore :

> ```
>  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
>   The constructor Scanner(InputStream) is undefined
>   The method nextLine() is undefined for the type Scanner
> ```

and this is my code :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Scanner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(myScanner.nextLine());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that you're also *declaring* a class called `Scanner`. That means that when you then declare a variable of type `Scanner` and try to call the constructor, the compiler thinks you're talking about *your* class. Just change your own class to something else (e.g. `Test`):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(myScanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Alternatively you *could* just fully-qualify the name when you mean `java.util.Scanner` - but this would be a bad idea in terms of readability.

```
// Please don't do this - but it would work.
public class Scanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.util.Scanner myScanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(myScanner.nextLine());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
java.util.Scanner myScanner = new java.util.Scanner(System.in);
```

instead. Else the compiler tries to instantiate your class which is also called `Scanner`. Or just rename your own `Scanner` class to something else.

Answer (score 2):

Please change the name of your class:

```
public class Scanner {
```

to some other name. The compiler is unable to see Scanner as `java.util.Scanner` because it sees it as your class (which doesn't have such constructor nor method so it gives you errors informing about it).

Answer (score 2):

Try to change your class name eg:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ScannerTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(myScanner.nextLine());

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should give class name as different then API classes of Java.So just change class name from `Scanner` to `ScannerProgram`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

     public class ScannerProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(myScanner.nextLine());

    }

}
```