# How to test a toString() method?

Tags: java

If I have something like this:

```
public class Set {

    private ArrayList<String> testList;
    private String testString;

    public Set() {
    }

    public void add(String testString) {
        testList.add(testString);
    }

    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(testString).append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

How can I test this in a main method?
This is what I've tried so far...

```
Set test = new Set();
test.add("blah");
test.add("blahhh");
System.out.println(blah.toString());
```

Am I doing this correctly? Taking my first CS course in High School and we're supposed to make a class that implements a toString() method.

Comment: `System.out.println(blah.toString());` What is `blah`? This will give you compile error if you haven't declared `blah`. Test it like this: `System.out.println(test);`

Comment: Your `toString` will output `null`. You never set the `testString` field.

Comment: You can also get the line separator using just [`System.lineSeparator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#lineSeparator()).

Comment: Side note: never name your types with names which already exist in Java. This can lead to many problems, for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17462795/cant-use-scanner-class-constructor-is-undefined-method-is-undefined.

Comment: You need to set the `testString` instance variable using `this.testString = testString;` in your `add` method.

Comment: The given code will throw a `NullPointerException`, since `testList` is never initialized. To fix this, replace `private ArrayList<String> testList;` with `private ArrayList<String> testList = new ArrayList<>();`.

Answer (score 0):

you creacted the object test of the class Set just write now just:

```
System.out.println(test);
```

will give you the result you want since it will use the toString method

and your testString is not set so the toString will return null

Answer (score 0):

You can test your toString this way, but for this purpose you should use Unit Tests (see [junit](http://junit.org/junit4/)).

For testing your Class you should try it with different types of input, to see, what happens, if someone enteres something unexpected.

And you have errors in your Code:

```
Set test = new Set();
test.add("blah");
test.add("blahhh");
System.out.println(blah.toString());
```

There is no blah variable:

```
System.out.println(test.toString());
```

or just:

```
System.out.println(test);
```

For learning purposes you should do something more usefull in your toString. You could try to create a Class bank account with balance, owner data (name, address, ...) and creating in the toString an interesting output.

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about testing; then dont go for **print** statements.
Turn to a unit test environment, like JUnit; and write *real* tests:

```
@Test
public testToStringWithTwoEntries() {
  Set underTest = new Set();
  underTest.add(...
  assertThat(underTest.toString(), is("blah, blahhh"));
}
```

for example. Notes:

- assertThat() is simply one of the most powerful of the various different assert methods; and it is easy to use; one just has to understand that it requires Hamcrest matchers to work (that is where the `is()` call is coming from)
- you named your class "Set" ... **bad** idea. There is already a well-known interface java.util.Set. You *never* want to re-use such names.

Answer (score 0):

A very good library for testing toString on model classes: https://github.com/jparams/to-string-verifier

Sample:

```
@Test
public void myTest()
{
    ToStringVerifier.forClass(Set.class).verify();
}
```